# Trying to convert timezone from UTC to EST

Tags: python, python-3.x

Time fetch through the API is showing me the UTC timezone and I am unable to convert it to Eastern timezone. Here is my code.

```
def convert_since():
  current_utc_time = packages_json['query']['since']
  print(current_utc_time)    
  new_zone = current_utc_time.replace("T", " ").replace("Z", " ")
  print(new_zone)                                         
  dt_est = new_zone.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
  print(dt_est)
  # return current_utc_time[:-1]
```

Current output 2019-10-18 14:30:00 and I am expecting the new output with the Eastern Timezone.

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astimezone'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert your `current_utc_time = packages_json['query']['since']` to a datetime. Depending on the format of that string, you can parse it with `datetime.strptime`. You will also need to cast your current datetime as utc with `.replace`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

current_utc_time = '2019-10-18T14:30:00Z' # packages_json['query']['since']
new_zone = current_utc_time.replace("T", " ").replace("Z", "")
print(new_zone)
dt_est = datetime.strptime(new_zone, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
print(dt_est)
```

Output:

```
2019-10-18 14:30:00
2019-10-18 10:30:00-04:00
```

You can also take out the string `.replace` and just add it to the format in strptime:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz


current_utc_time = '2019-10-18T14:30:00Z' # packages_json['query']['since']
print(current_utc_time)
dt_est = datetime.strptime(current_utc_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
print(dt_est)
```

Comment: I have tried but here is the output 
#### Before 2019-10-18T15:15:00Z
AFTER *******
2019-10-18 15:15:00-04:00

Comment: It seems to be working. However, it's not converting the%H:%M:%S

Comment: You need to set the timezone on the parsed datetime object. It's basically defining that the current datetime is in UTC. Don't forget the `.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)`

Comment: I'm glad that it worked! Working with timezones can be tricky sometimes.

Comment: I agree with you, it was very tricky. I have spent few hours before I post here and finally have a solution and I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

So your variable `new_zone` is a string, and you are calling a method `.astimezone` that requires `new_zone` to be in datetime format.

Try:

```
datetime.strptime(new_zone, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I have tried but it gave me the following error
def convert_since():
 current_utc_time = packages_json['query']['since']
 print(current_utc_time[:-1])
 new_zone = current_utc_time.replace("T", " ").replace("Z", " ")
 print(new_zone)
 ti = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_zone, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
 print(ti)
 dt_est = ti.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
 print(dt_est)
 return current_utc_time[:-1]


ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Comment: This is also a valid answer!!